# Play MP3 from stream

Tags: c#, database, vb.net, mp3, stream

Is there any way to play MP3 directly from a memory stream (without any temp. files) using VB.NET or C#? or play from SQLCe database?

Thanks

Comment: Um, do you mean Valve Software's game-distribution engine [Steam](http://www.steampowered.com/), or do you mean a [stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream%28VS.71%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll suggest you try [Mp3Sharp](http://www.robburke.net/mle/mp3sharp/). It is a port of JavaLayer and it is written in C#. I am currently using it and SlimDX to play ShoutCast Mp3 streams. So far it works very well.  
There is an Mp3Stream class which you use to read the stream and return a predetermined number of PCM bytes. You can write those bytes to a DirectSound buffer for playback if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

[IrrKlang](http://www.ambiera.com/irrklang/) can also do this for you.